# Which qubit has the highest $|1\rangle$ amplitude?

Tags: quantum-state, circuit-construction

Suppose I can prepare $n$ qubits each in an unknown independent state (not entangled). If needed, you can assume that each qubit is in a state $a_i |0\rangle + b_i |1\rangle$ for real numbers $a$ and $b$. Is there a quantum circuit that can answer the question "which qubit has the most overlap with $|1\rangle$?" more efficiently than directly measuring each qubit individually? You can apply any number of single- or multi-bit quantum operations to the data before measuring some subset of the qubits. The quantum algorithm does not necessarily need to be asymptotically efficient; the goal is to to minimize the number of measurement shots needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Single-shot circuit of this sort would enable FTL comms, so is not possible. Multiple-shot variant can be realized using for example Quantum State Tomography or (more efficiently) [Direct Fidelity Estimation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4695).

### Faster-than-light communication protocol

We'll use the single-shot variant of the desired quantum circuit to construct a communication protocol that allows Alice to send a classical bit to Bob faster than light and with arbitrarily low error probability $\epsilon$.

Suppose Alice and Bob share $N$ Bell pairs $(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)/\sqrt2=(|{++}\rangle+|{--}\rangle)/\sqrt2$ where $N=\lceil\log_2 \frac{1}{\epsilon}\rceil$. Let's name Alice's qubits $q_1,\dots,q_N$ and Bob's qubits $q_{N+1},\dots,q_{2N}$. Also, let $\Phi:\mathbb{C}^2\otimes\mathbb{C}^2\to\{0,1\}$ denote the desired operation. Given a product state $|\psi_0\rangle\otimes|\psi_1\rangle$ the operation returns $k\in\{0,1\}$ if $|\psi_k\rangle$ has greater overlap with $|1\rangle$ than $|\psi_{1-k}\rangle$. In particular,
$$
\begin{align}
\Phi(|{+}\rangle\otimes|1'\rangle)&=1\\
\Phi(|{-}\rangle\otimes|1'\rangle)&=1\\
\Phi(|0\rangle\otimes|1'\rangle)&=1\\
\Phi(|1\rangle\otimes|1'\rangle)&=0\\
\end{align}\tag1
$$
where $|1'\rangle=\sqrt{1-\delta^2}|1\rangle+\delta|0\rangle$ for a sufficiently small$^1$ $\delta>0$.
In fact, these four equalities are all that is necessary to construct an FTL communication protocol.

Let $v_A\in\{0,1\}$ denote the bit that Alice wishes to send to Bob. She proceeds as follows: if $v_A=0$, she measures qubits $q_1,\dots,q_N$ in the Pauli $Z$ basis, otherwise she measures them in the Pauli $X$ basis. Bob proceeds in three steps:

1. First, he prepares $N$ auxiliary qubits $q_{2N+1},\dots,q_{3N}$ in the $|1'\rangle$ state.
2. Next, for $k=1,\dots,N$, he applies $\Phi$ to $q_{N+k}$ and $q_{2N+k}$ denoting the resulting classical bit with $b_k$.
3. Finally, if Bob finds any $k$ for which $b_k=0$, then he sets $v_B=0$, otherwise he sets $v_B=1$.

### Error probability

The key observation is that if Alice performed the measurement in the $X$ basis, then $q_{N+k}$ collapses to $|+\rangle$ about half the time and to $|-\rangle$ about half the time. Otherwise it collapses to $|0\rangle$ about half the time and to $|1\rangle$ about half the time. Thus, if $v_A=1$, then $b_k=1$ for all $k=1,\dots,N$ with certainty, and if $v_A=0$, then $b_k=0$ with probability $\frac12$ and $b_k=1$ with probability $\frac12$ independently for all $k=1,\dots,N$.

Thus, if $v_A=1$, then Bob will always see $b_k=1$ for all $k=1,\dots,N$, so the probability of error is
$$
P(v_A\ne v_B\,|\,v_A=1)=0.\tag2
$$
Conversely, if Bob found a $k$ with $b_k=0$, then Alice must have$^2$ set $v_A=0$ and
$$
P(v_A\ne v_B\,|\,v_B=0)=0.\tag3
$$

On the other hand, if $v_A=0$, then either Bob finds a $k$ for which $b_k=0$ (in which case $v_A=v_B$) or $b_k=1$ for all $k=1,\dots,N$ (in which case $v_A\ne v_B$). The latter situation can only happen when every Bell pair collapsed to $|11\rangle$. This happens with probability
$$
P(v_A\ne v_B\,|\,v_A=0)=\left(\frac12\right)^N=\frac{1}{2^{\lceil\log_2 \frac{1}{\epsilon}\rceil}}\leqslant\frac{1}{2^{\log_2 \frac{1}{\epsilon}}}=\epsilon\tag4
$$
which can be made arbitrarily small by choosing appropriate $N$.

N.B. this type of classical channel is known as a [Z-channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-channel_(information_theory)) or binary asymmetric channel.

---

<sup>$^1$ We introduce $\delta$ to make the protocol independent of the way $\Phi$ breaks ties when the two qubits have the same overlap with $|1\rangle$. Without $\delta$ the last equation in $(1)$ depends on this tie-breaking behavior.

$^2$ Or "*will* set $v_A=1$" since if Alice and Bob are spacelike separated, then there are observers who will see Bob receive the bit before Alice sent it.</sup>

Comment: Very interesting!

Comment: Yes, it is interesting to think about, isn't it? It's as if measurements created a noisy FTL channel and we're using a repetition code to deal with the noise.

Comment: At the core all this follows a fairly usual script: one defines an operation by specifying its action on a set strictly larger than a basis and the operation turns out not to be linear. Once you've introduced non-linearity, quantum mechanics can do all kinds of weird things. This suggests a simpler proof that $\Phi$ doesn't exist (hint: try to define it as a POVM), but it is more tedious and less fun than FTL comms!

Comment: Yes!! How did you come up with this answer? What was your thought process after reading the question?

Comment: I had thought about the fact that Alice's choice of measurement basis on half of Bell pair causes Bob's state to collapse to 50-50 mixture of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ or to 50-50 mixture of $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$ depending on Alice's choice. These are both maximally mixed state, but if Bob had operation (necessarily non-linear) to distinguish the two mixtures, then he'd be able to tell what basis Alice chose/will choose. I just noticed that the proposed circuit meets the requirements of that dreamed-up operation Bob needs. The rest is standard use of repetition code to correct errors.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer! It makes sense that this cannot be done in a single-shot way. However, can it be done using fewer shots than would be required to measure each qubit in the Z basis individually? For example, is there some quantum circuit that could encode the index of the highest-$|1\rangle$-amplitude qubit into a smaller number of qubits, which could then be read out over some smaller total number of shots?